# Utilizing nonce in MUI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, express, content-security-policy, nonce

Does anybody know how to embed nonce genereated straight by server side inside MUI component?
I have no idea what possibilities are to send it from server written in Express JS and put it inside html generated by React JS. The MUI docs are too poor to conclude something robust for CSP nonce related implementation.

This is what I made so far:

[image: generating nonce anytime request comes]

I want to obtain MUI component fully working, ensuring better CSP for inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that i found it:
1- In the server I replace all the `$nonce` in the public.html page

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // Generate a new random nonce for each request
  const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')

  // Set the CSP header in the response
  res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', res.getHeader('Content-Security-Policy').replace(`$nonce`, nonce))
  let indexHtml = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'),
    'utf-8'
  )

  // Inject the nonce into the script tag
  indexHtml = indexHtml.replaceAll('$nonce', nonce)

  // Set the modified HTML as the response
  res.send(indexHtml)
});
```

2- In my public/index.html i added this two lines:

```
<meta property="csp-nonce" content="$nonce" />
<script data-nonce="$nonce"></script>
```

3- To get that value i select the script tag then i get the value from there

```
export function getNonce() {
  // Find the script tag with the nonce attribute
  const scriptWithNonce = document.querySelector('script[data-nonce]');
  // Extract the nonce value
  const nonce = scriptWithNonce?.getAttribute('data-nonce') || '';
  return nonce
}
```

4- Last thing is to pass the nonce to Datagrid component

```
DataGridPro.defaultProps = {
  nonce: getNonce(),
}
```